# no account logout Django Two factor auth

Tags: django, django-two-factor-auth

i am trying to implement two factor auth in my Django app. However, the user can bypass it by using the login provided by django.contrib.auth. is there any way i can redirect the user to /account/login when they browse for /login?

**Things i tried and have not work:**

- removing django.contrib.auth (need this to logout)

[redundant login urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8l23.png)

settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
    'booking.apps.BookingConfig',
    'formtools',
    'register.apps.RegisterConfig',
    "crispy_forms",
    'django_otp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_static',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_email',  # <- if you want email capability.
    'two_factor',
    'two_factor.plugins.email',  # <- if you want email capability.

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",

    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

LOGIN_URL = 'two_factor:login'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['some random header']
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'register.User'
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from register import views as v
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from two_factor.urls import urlpatterns as tf_urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("main.urls")),
    path("register/",v.register, name="register"),
    path('booking/', include("booking.urls")),
    path('',include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path('', include(tf_urls)),
]
```

Comment: Do you use `/login` URL?

Comment: my apologies, i did not clarify enough. its already added. but the problem is that user can manually browse the page by adding /login after the URL which could bypass it.

Example:
127.0.0.1:8000/login  would bring them to the default login instead of /account/login by two factor auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, i found another solution. Here's how i did it. This Django two factor auth lacks redirect URL. So instead of using two factor auth use [2fa](https://github.com/neutron-sync/django-2fa/tree/main/django_2fa/templates). it works well with the build in django.contrib.auth. after logging in using the built in login, you can redirect the user to the 2fa login which is exactly what i wanted.

- check the documentation for more details :).

settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL = "/login"
MFA_URL = '/2fa/login'
MFA_REDIRECT_FIELD = 'next'
MFA_PROTECT_PATH_STARTSWITH = None

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"

SALT_KEY = "skfmrgfhtolstehsmgocbetshtpanrpshtnf" #this is just random 36 character
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...extra paths,
    path('2fa/', include(django_2fa.urls)),
    path('',include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this inside settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL = 'two_factor:login'
```